# How make an Android widget with Cordova?

Tags: visual-studio-cordova

The [Microsoft ACE](https://github.com/Microsoft/ace) plugin provided a way to make an Android widget.

Now that the plugin is discontinued, what is the recommended way of making a widget with Cordova?

Comment: As far as I know, currently there is no other easy way of making android native widget. You can fork ACE and change the source codes yourself to make it meet your requirement.

Comment: Thanks, @ElvisXia-MSFT

Comment: There's some sample source code here you might try https://www.infohit.net/blog/post/getting-started-with-an-android-widget-populated-with-javascript-and-apache-cordova/